# Cakephp testAction() is not sending a json payload to controller

Tags: cakephp, testing

I am trying to test a controller function that accepts a json payload.

As per the documentation of testAction() this can be done via setting $options['data'] to the appropriate string. Its not working for me.
See the documentation quoted here: http://api20.cakephp.org/class/controller-test-case (Please scroll down the the testAction() section).

Here is my test case.

```
public function testCreate(){
    //Some code here
    $this->testAction('/shippingbatches/create', array('data' => '[3,6]', 'method' => 'post'));
    //Some more code here
}
```

Here is my controller function

```
public function create(){        
    debug($this->request); //This debug shows me an empty array in $this->request->data
    ob_flush();
    $order_ids = json_decode($this->request->data);
    //Some more code here
}
```

The first line of the controller function is showing me an empty array in $this->request->data. If the 'data' passed from the testAction() is an actual array it comes in nice & fine. But not when it is set to a string (unlike it says in the documentation).

Here is the output of the debug.

```
object(Mock_CakeRequest_ef4431a5) {
    params => array(
        'plugin' => null,
        'controller' => 'shippingbatches',
        'action' => 'create',
        'named' => array(),
        'pass' => array(),
        'return' => (int) 1,
        'bare' => (int) 1,
        'requested' => (int) 1
    )
    data => array()
    query => array(
        'case' => 'Controller\ShippingBatchesController'
    )
    url => 'shippingbatches/create'
    base => ''
    webroot => '/'
    here => '/shippingbatches/create'
}
```

Please help.

Gurpreet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When passing data like that, you must receive it using [`CakeRequest::input()`](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/cake-request#method-CakeRequestinput).

```
public function create() {
    $json = $this->request->input('json_decode', true);  
    debug($json);
}
```

I should note that I discovered this by reading Cake's test cases for [`ControllerTestCase::testAction`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Test/Case/TestSuite/ControllerTestCaseTest.php#L435). Reading test cases can give you insight into how Cake's internals work and give you hints on writing tests.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I wonder, though, how you got the idea from reading the test...

Comment: That test uses the test app's `TestsAppsPostsController::input_data()`. Looking in there, I found that `CakeRequest::input()` was used to grab the input.